# Save nested attributes in form but without parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using nested attributes (`accepts_nested_attributes_for`) and the form submits and works, except that it saves the 'parent' object, but I don't want it to (the parent object is Physician, and that's already created when the user signs up - I just want the nested attributes - appointments - to save)

- Currently the new and create actions for Physician are the same as the scaffold default
- physician_params looks like `params.require(:physician).permit(:time_slot, availabilities_attributes: [:id, :time_slot, :_destroy])`

I can get the Physician and many Availabilities to save, but I only want the Availabilities to save (not the Physician, that's already created).

It's probably really simple, but I can't spot it in docs / tutorials

Here is the Physicians create method

```
  def create
    @physician = Physician.new(physician_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @physician.save
        format.html { redirect_to @physician, notice: 'Physician was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @physician }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @physician.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: You probably want to be in the `AvailabilitiesController` not the `PhysiciansController`.

Answer (score 2):

Jvillian has the better approach. Since your Physician already exists you should be using an AvailabilitiesController with a new method like this:

```
def new
  @physician = Physician.find(params['physician_id'])
  @availability = @physician.availabilities.build
end
```

Also you probably want a nested resources under physician like:

```
resources :physicians do
  resources :availabilities
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create 2 different tables. One table for the physicians and one for the appointments. Link them through each model

```
class Physician < ApplicationRecord
has_many :appointments
```

```
class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :physician
```

It's much easier to handle and you can create appointments seperately for every physician you want (or for one specific). So every physician is able to create only his appointments or assign appointments to whatever physician he/she wants.

Comment: I believe he already has something similar to this.